# How to calculate the interpolation between two colors correctly?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I created a progress bar, and I like to change it's color as it makes the progress. From green to red (it is counting down).
The problem is, that the progress bar changes too quickly to red, and between the green and red stage, it has multiple colors. Basically I want something like VLC has:

[image]

My code:

```
typedef struct RgbColor
{
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
} RgbColor;

typedef struct HsvColor
{
  unsigned char h;
  unsigned char s;
  unsigned char v;
} HsvColor;

template<typename F>
RgbColor interpolate( RgbColor a, RgbColor b, float t, F interpolator )
{
  // 0.0 <= t <= 1.0
  HsvColor ca = RgbToHsv1( a );
  HsvColor cb = RgbToHsv1( b );
  HsvColor final;

  final.h = interpolator( ca.h, cb.h, t );
  final.s = interpolator( ca.s, cb.s, t );
  final.v = interpolator( ca.v, cb.v, t );

  return HsvToRgb1( final );
}

int linear( int a, int b, float t )
{
   return a * ( 1 - t ) + b * t;
}
```

And then in WndProc:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{ 
    float CurrentStep = SendMessage( hwndPB, PBM_GETPOS, 0, 0 );
    static float MaxStep = SendMessage( hwndPB, PBM_GETRANGE, 0, 0 );
    static RgbColor result;
        static BOOL bFirst = TRUE;

        if ( bFirst )
        {
            result.r = 36;
            result.g = 149;
            result.b = 16;
            bFirst = FALSE;
        }

        RgbColor startColor, endColor;
        startColor.r = result.r;
        startColor.g = result.g;
        startColor.b = result.b;
        endColor.r = 183;
        endColor.g = 13;
        endColor.b = 14;
            float test = ( CurrentStep / MaxStep ) / 100;
            result = interpolate( startColor, endColor, test, &linear )
           SendMessage( hwndPB, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, RGB( result.r, result.g, result.b) );
        SendMessage( hwndPB, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0 );

}
break;
```

Could someone please help me?

**Edit:**
This is the progressbar how I have it now.
[image]

In this case, the time is set to 200, and it is counting back from there, and about 50 seconds later it looks like this. About more 10 seconds, and it has reached the target color, which isn't right. I also noticed, if I set the Timer to 20 seconds, then it stays green. I think there wasn't enough time to start changing the color, so my calculations are wrong.

Changing the formula to t^2 or t^3 or bigger has also not the effect which I expect.

Comment: Can you have a struct array of 101 values of r,b,g for each percentage progress?

Comment: That screenshot of VLC seems like the change is nonlinear.  You need to use a function that changes slowly at first and then accelerates.  You could try using t^2 like this: `t = t*t; return a * ( 1 - t ) + b * t;`.  If that isn't enough, try t^3, t^4, etc..  Or use another function.  Btw it would be helpful to see a screenshot of your current linear attempt.

Comment: Why does this line: `float test = ( CurrentStep / MaxStep ) / 100;` have a divide by 100 in it?  Shouldn't it just be `float test = ( CurrentStep / MaxStep );`?

Comment: @JS1: as far as I understand the things, it should be a percentage of the progress. If I remove the `/100` it will start as red immidiately

Comment: Don't do it as a single gradient, do it in multiple segments. Move the endpoints of the segments around until it works the way you want.

Comment: @MarkRansom: sorry, but I don't fully understand this inerpolation. I am happy, that it works this way. Took me the whole day. Could you explain a little bit more, what and how I should do?

Comment: @kampi sorry I don't have time for a full-blown answer right now, maybe later today.

Comment: @MarkRansom: JS1 already solved my problem, but still thanks.

Comment: [Linear interpolation is the wrong thing to do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Moving targets

Your current code is not interpolating between the start color and the end color.  It is interpolating between the **current** color and the end color, which makes your interpolation accelerate too quickly.  These lines:

```
    startColor.r = result.r;
    startColor.g = result.g;
    startColor.b = result.b;
```

should be changed to:

```
    startColor.r = 36;
    startColor.g = 149;
    startColor.b = 16;
```

### Percentage already factored in

The next problem is that this line here:

```
float test = ( CurrentStep / MaxStep ) / 100;
```

should be changed to:

```
float test = ( CurrentStep / MaxStep );
```

This is assuming that CurrentStep ranges from 0..MaxStep.  If for some reason CurrentStep ranges from 0..100*MaxStep, then your current code would be correct.

### Which way is CurrentStep moving?

The other thing that might be happening is that CurrentStep is starting at MaxStep and counting down toward 0.  In that case, your code should be:

```
float test = 1.0f - ( CurrentStep / MaxStep );
```

Comment: You are right. You find all my errors. Now it is working fine. Thank you!